# What is the verification process of nodes on chainLink?

Tags: oracles, chainlink

chainLink is a decentralized system similar to Ethereum, which can help smart contracts execute get requests and return the results. The result of chainLink execution also needs to be verified by other nodes on the network. I want to know what is the verification process of other nodes on chainLink. Do other nodes need to initiate a get request to the same url when verifying, and then verify based on the result?

Hope you can give me some help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can spin up a Chainlink node and list their node on [market.link](https://market.link/) or any other node listing services.

Just follow along with the [documentation](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node%5C). It is good to note that Chainlink nodes are not like other nodes, they are [digital businesses](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/the-ultimate-guide-to-running-a-chainlink-node-a7f2c3ff4eb1?source=friends_link&sk=3ff02da0d3538ab0f7f8695d9e80cab3) where you have to get clients. One of the best ways to do this is by joining the community, and helping engineers become successful. This is a great way to gain trust from engineers.